# TextInputEditText disappears when created as part of a popup-window

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this weird problem in Android. When I create a popup-window with the following code, the TextInputEditText in the TextInputLayout disappears. This popup is created in a normal initially empty activity that extends AppCompatActivity.

```
private void createPopupWindow() {
        // inflate the layout of the popup window
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window_two, null);

        // create the popup window
        int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        boolean focusable = false; // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);

        popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        createOkButton();
    }
```

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputGroupNameLayout"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/tan"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.055">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Group Name" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The hint in the TextInputEditText shows up for a split second, but does not stay, and the user is not able to input text.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! :) It is just a "normal" activity that extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: Does the size of the pop-up window change after the `TextInputEditText` vanishes?

Comment: No! I fixed this problem now by using alerts instead (so not really fixed, but at least the app works now). Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard doesn't show up because you pass the `focusable` parameter of `PopupWindow` as `false`. You need to pass `true` if you want to be able to show it.

The behaviour you see with the `TextInputEditText` hint is caused by the fact that the input automatically requires the focus of the window. To avoid this add:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

To `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` which is the root element of your `popupView`.